# How to plot these graphics side by side?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have 2 diagrams and they superimposed on one another
How can i display them side by side?

```
sns.histplot(data=dataset.loc[dataset['Survived'] == 0, 'Age'], color='green') \      
 .set(xticks=range(0, 81, 5), title='Survived= 0');

 sns.histplot(data=dataset.loc[dataset['Survived'] == 1, 'Age'], color='purple') \
  .set(xticks=range(0, 81, 5), title='Survived= 1');
```

Comment: `sns.histplot(data=dataset, x='Age', hue='Survived', palette['green','purple'], multiple='dodge')`

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a figure object with two columns and pass the individual columns as ax keyword-arguments to sns.histplot, like so:

```
dataset = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

sns.histplot(data=dataset.loc[dataset['survived'] == 0, 'age'], color='green', ax=ax[0]).set(xticks=range(0, 81, 5), title='Survived= 0');

sns.histplot(data=dataset.loc[dataset['survived'] == 1, 'age'], color='purple', ax=ax[1]).set(xticks=range(0, 81, 5), title='Survived= 1');
```